Yocto glibc error in do_fetch for glibc library in cross compilation for qt based yocto image
While compiling Yocto for Renesas Board facing an issue in fetching the glibc library
Please find the log:
glibc-2.28-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1321"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/poky/scripts:build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux:build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:poky/bitbake/bin:/home/nitish/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.5/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="$DIR"; /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -O build/downloads/glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc.tmp -P /$TOPDIR/build/downloads 'https://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/glibc/glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc' --progress=dot -v failed with exit code 8, no output
ERROR: glibc-2.28-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'https://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/glibc/glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc;name=glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.285704
ERROR: Task (build/../meta-renesas/meta-rz-common/recipes-debian/buster/glibc/glibc_debian.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

I tried to refer to some of the alternate clones for the library but the error remains the same.
I tried to clone it using the wget command and clone repo manually but it failed with a 404 error.
any reference or solution will be very helpful.


I got the suggestion and the patch at the following link which resolved my glibc error.
as per the Renesas team this issue is resolved in V3.0.6-update3
for the reference: Glibc error resolution
Thank you @sopryshko for the guidence

I had the same problem with another library. My solution was to create a .bbappend recipe in one of the Yocto layers and provide an alternative source link.
If you try to access the current link manually, you'll get a 404 error, which means the file glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc is no longer available. However, if you check this link, you can find other .dsc packages that may work.
The content of your glibc_debian.bbappend file may look like this:
SRC_URI:remove = "https://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/glibc/glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc;name=glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc"

SRC_URI += "https://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/glibc/glibc_2.28-10+deb10u4.dsc;name=glibc_2.28-10+deb10u4.dsc"

Please note that the syntax of Yocto recipe may vary depending on your Yocto release.
Alternatively, you can find another source with the same library version.

I tried to download the exact same version as suggested and copied that to download directory but didn't get any help.

also I tried to create the .bbappend file as suggested no change in the behaviour of the build.
I also did clean build but no improvement.

@NitishSharma after creating the .bbappend, do you still have the "Bitbake Fetcher Error"? Could you please add the log after this step to your question, so I can take a look at it?

ERROR: glibc-2.28-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'https://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/glibc/glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc;name=glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/nitish/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.5/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.28-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.414242
ERROR: Task (/home/nitish/yocto/rzg_vlp_v3.0.5/build/../meta-renesas/meta-rz-common/recipes-debian/buster/glibc/glibc_debian.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

Verified the new layer and bbappend file is added in the local.conf file using bitbake command

I added the logs snapshot in the question itself

@NitishSharma so it's still trying to fetch glibc_2.28-10+deb10u2.dsc instead of glibc_2.28-10+deb10u4.dsc. Make sure that your glibc_debian.bbappend file is present in any Yocto layer. What's the output of this command: bitbake-layers show-appends glibc?
